# Using a WebGL canvas at pixel resolution while retaining perspective

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, webgl, pixel

I've seen this type of question here before, but none that gave me a full answer, so I'm going to post my code and see if anyone can give me any insight. Basically, this code works, but I have a magical z offset of (height * 1.205) [irrespective of width] and I have no idea why.

Setting the size and creating an alignment vector:

```
gl.viewportWidth = gl.canvas.width;
gl.viewportHeight = gl.canvas.height;
gl.viewportHalfWidth = gl.viewportWidth / 2;
gl.viewportHalfHeight = gl.viewportHeight / 2;
gl.viewportAspect = gl.viewportWidth / gl.viewportHeight;
gl.viewportZoom = -gl.viewportHeight * 1.205;
if (gl.alignmentTest) {
    gl.alignmentVertices = (new Buffer(    // TL, TM, BM, BR, TR, BL, TL
       [    1.0,                        -1.0,                    0.0,
        gl.viewportHalfWidth - 0.5,     -1.0,                    0.0,
        gl.viewportHalfWidth - 0.5, -(gl.viewportHeight - 1.0),  0.0,
        gl.viewportWidth - 1.0,     -(gl.viewportHeight - 1.0),  0.0,
        gl.viewportWidth - 1.0,         -1.0,                    0.0,
            1.0,                    -(gl.viewportHeight - 1.0),  0.0,
            1.0,                        -1.0,                    0.0], 3)).post();
}
```

Drawing the alignment vector:

```
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
mat4.perspective(45, gl.viewportAspect, 0.1, 1000.0, gl.perspective.current);
gl.perspective.post();    // ^ writes directly to current perspective buffer

gl.modelView.resetToIdentity();

gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// Translate to pixel resolution
gl.modelView.push();
gl.modelView.translate([-gl.viewportHalfWidth, gl.viewportHalfHeight, gl.viewportZoom]);
gl.modelView.post();

// Alignment test?
if (gl.alignmentTest && gl.alignmentVertices) {
    gl.red.useAsAttribute(gl.shaderProg.vertexColour);
    gl.zero.vec2.useAsAttribute(gl.shaderProg.vertexTextureCoord);
    gl.alignmentVertices.drawAsPrimitives(gl.shaderProg.vertexPosition, gl.LINE_STRIP);
}

gl.disable(gl.BLEND);
```

The lines in question are:

```
gl.viewportZoom = -gl.viewportHeight * 1.205;
```

and:

```
gl.modelView.translate([-gl.viewportHalfWidth, gl.viewportHalfHeight, gl.viewportZoom]);
```

This code works for *any* size.

Here's a screenshot at 700x300: http://oi49.tinypic.com/2my9ir7.jpg

And another at 400x600: http://oi46.tinypic.com/i2irh3.jpg

So the question is: Why does this magical scaling factor of 1.205 exist? Or what could I be doing wrong to make it necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You want to draw a quad, using 3D math, such that it draws at 1x1 pixel? The first obvious answer is "why are you using 3d math to draw 2d?" Just draw in 2D with 2D math". (http://goo.gl/xQvx1) But, if you must draw in 3D for some reason the second answer is "use an othrographic matrix".

Comment: The primitive I'm drawing is just an example to make sure WebGL space is aligned relative to the canvas border. This particular interface needs to integrate classical 2D objects into 3D space, and also allow 3D objects to be manipulated from within a 2D interface, so trying to draw a distinction between the two and treat them separately is not ideal. And it shouldn't matter. What I have works fine, and isn't really hacky either. I just want to know why it requires a magic number so I can replace it with the correct calculation.

Comment: There is no "WebGL space". WebGL is just a rectangle of pixels and some GLSL functions you supply. What you do with it is up to you. WebGL does not define a space. You do. Would you please consider changing the title of your question so it makes some sense? How about "How do I align a textured unit quad in 3D space so it displays at 1x1 pixels in a canvas"?

Comment: Sorry. The title was indeed misleading. I'm not so much asking how - I'm happy with the method I have now - but rather, why [I end up with a magic number]. I'm quite happy with Kevin's answer below. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked out the math, but I'm guessing that that factor arises from the FOV and near-plane of your *perspective* projection matrix. Most applications attempting to get 1:1 pixels do not also use perspective projection.

If you have reason to use perspective, then I suggest not using FOV-based perspective calculations and instead use frustum-based (`glFrustum`-alike) — it is much easier to actually derive the effects of a projection frustum, and you could work out that correction factor from first principles rather than adjusting it by hand.

---

This is essentially a trigonometric problem. Imagine the view frustum, or rather the view pyramid (i.e. not cut off by the near and far planes); it has its tip at the “camera position” and four sloping faces. The FOV as conventionally defined is equal to the angle between the top and bottom faces (this is why, as you mention, the width has no influence). However, for your purposes, the parameter you care about is not the angle, but the *slope* (ratio of Z to X-or-Y movement) — which is where your arbitrary figure comes from.

If we look at [the documentation for good ol' `gluPerspective`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml) (which I am going to assume is using the same math as your perspective operation is using), it says:  `f  = cotangent(fovy/2)`. This is exactly the calculation we care about. (If trying to reproduce this, note that most trig functions in math libraries take angles in radians, not degrees.)

The factor of 2 occurs because FOV is conventionally measured as the full view angle, but the value of interest is half of that — the angle between “straight ahead” and “just at the edge of the view”.

As you may know, the value of the cotangent (or tangent) function can be interpreted as a slope. This slope *f* above tells you exactly the ratio between Z movement and X-or-Y movement; for example, if you scale an object by some value `d`, and also move it along the Z axis by `f*d`, then it will not appear to change size. This may be exactly what your `viewportZoom` is already doing:

```
f / 2 = cot(45° / 2) / 2 ≈ 1.207106
```

which is pretty close to your 1.205. If this is in fact the case, I haven't worked out where the factor of 2 is coming from.

All you need to do is compute `f` once (or possibly its reciprocal `tan(fovy/2)` depending on which is more convenient in the end) and use it both to compute your "zoom" distances and your projection matrix.

---

(By the way, your code contains a lot of stuff that is not WebGL, e.g. `Buffer`, `post`, `drawAsPrimitives`, etc. It would be potentially helpful if you mentioned what library you are using.)

Comment: Thanks. I did initially think it was FOV-related but if that was the case I would've expected width to have an influence. Do you know of any good resources explaining how FOV works? All I've ever seen is "This is your field of view. Set it to 45."


I'm mixing 2D objects, 3D objects and a second canvas overlay (for editing the interface), so I do need both full perspective and 1:1 pixels. I can't say I know anything about frustums, really, but I thought they were dependent on the projection matrix. Maybe I'm not understanding something though.

Comment: (Regarding the library: it's my own, and it's very much incomplete. I'll be happy to share it if people want to use it but I figured it was intuitive enough for the scope of the question.)

Comment: @jimmetry I've added some discussion of FOV math.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it further, but your answer makes a lot of sense, especially with FOV being vertical-only, so I've accepted it.